# PHP gd JPEG image support missing

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, httpd, php5, gd

I have a centos 7 server and need multiple versions of PHP. I am compiling PHP 5.6 and the php application needs to support GD Jpeg. I have the following error.

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/php-5.6.28 .... --with-freetype-dir --with-freetype-dir --with-gd --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-png-dir --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/lib/
```

--with-jpeg-dir=/usr/local/lib/ **or** /usr **or** /usr/lib64..

Output:

```
checking for GD support... yes
checking for the location of libvpx... no
checking for the location of libjpeg... /usr/local/lib/
checking for the location of libpng... yes
checking for the location of libXpm... no
checking for FreeType 2... yes
```

Installed: 
**yum install libjpeg-devel gd - OK**

Return:
**PHP gd JPEG image support missing.**

Find Lib:

```
/usr/libjpeg.so
/usr/local/lib/libjpeg.so
/usr/lib64/libjpeg.so
/usr/lib/libjpeg.so
```

Does anyone know if any library is missing to install or make a somber link?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you actually compile it and install it after running configure?  Configure doesn't do that.

Comment: Hi. Yes. I'm running make and make install

Comment: Resolved.

I used the repository repository. Cool

https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2016/04/16/My-PHP-Workstation